# How do I set environment variables for Selenium Java FirefoxDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

From within Java unit tests, I want to use Selenium to test my web page with Firefox. My tests require that I set an environment variable for Firefox. (Specifically, I want to set the DISPLAY variable.)

The `FirefoxBinary` class has a method [setEnvironmentProperty](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxBinary.html#setEnvironmentProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), which sounds like it should set environment variables for the environment the Firefox process runs in, but in practice it does not have that effect. (I have confirmed that with `cat /proc/<firefox_pid>/environ`.)

Back with selenium-java 3.0.1, I could build a `GeckoDriverService` with custom environment variables, and the `FirefoxDriver` constructor accepted the driver service as an argument, like so:

```
Map<String, String> customEnvironmentMap = new HashMap<>();
customEnvironmentMap.put("DISPLAY", ":1");
GeckoDriverService driverService = new GeckoDriverService.Builder(binary)
        .withEnvironment(customEnvironmentMap)
        .usingPort(0)
        .build()
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(driverService, capabilities, null);
```

The custom variables would be present in the environment of the geckodriver process and the environment of the Firefox process.

That constructor is not present in version 3.4.0, and `FirefoxDriver` uses a private method to create the driver service, so I can't customize it. So, how do I configure the environment of the Firefox process that Selenium launches?

My current workaround is to substitute a script like this one for the geckodriver executable path:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /usr/bin/env DISPLAY=:1 /path/to/geckodriver $@
```

I don't really like this technique, for various reasons (it's hacky, I have to create a temp file for the script in the filesystem, etc.).

Comment: So, you need to specify FF binary path? If yes, use FirefoxProfile and look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24891650/1967021

Comment: I need to set the DISPLAY environment variable.

Comment: what do you mean by display environment for Firefox? isn't that the system environment variable?

Comment: I want to set the value of the DISPLAY variable in Firefox's environment to a value different from the system's DISPLAY environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Selenium 3.7.1, the constructor that takes a `GeckoDriverService` has returned, so you can once again do the following:

```
Map<String, String> environment = new HashMap<>();
environment.put("DISPLAY", ":1");
GeckoDriverService service = new GeckoDriverService.Builder()
        .usingAnyFreePort()
        .withEnvironment(environment)
        .build();
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this website help? https://testautomationarchives.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-configure-selenium-webdriver.html.

Starting at Step 5 from the above site, since 1-4 are installing things:

Step 5 : Set Environment Variables (Windows 7 )

1. Right Click On Computer
2. Click on Properties
3. Click On ‘Advance Settings’
4. On  ‘System Properties ‘  Click On tab ‘Advance’
5. Click on ‘Environment Variables ‘
6. Copy  following path where JDK  is installed. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin
7. On Environment Variable Window  Click ‘New’ Under System Variable 
   and Set  Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin. If Path Variable already Exist Then Edit it .
8. Set  CLASSPATH : Copy  following Path Where JDK is installed :
9. On Environment Variable Window Click ‘New’ under  User Variables and
   Set  CLASSPATH :
10. Enviornment is set up now  start JAVA IDE

Comment: Thanks, but I think not. Those instructions are for setting the system or user environment variables, but I want to customize environment variables only for the Firefox process.